# How to add one to a variable to make 2 not 11

Tags: javascript, html

Currently this makes 11. It's for a slideshow and the var "n" equals 1 by default

```
function forward() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("img")[0].setAttribute("class","imgout");
    setTimeout( function() {
        var n1 = document.getElementById("img").getAttribute("data-number");
        var n=n1+1;
        document.getElementById("img").setAttribute("data-number", n);
        document.getElementById("img").setAttribute("src", "images/" + n + ".jpg");
        document.getElementsByClassName("imgout")[0].setAttribute("class","img");
    }, 500)
}
```

Comment: In fact, `n` equals `"1"`, and `"1" + 1 = "11"`.

Comment: @apsillers how do I correct that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
var n=n1+1;
```

When n1 will be a string, because it came from the DOM, you need to convert n1 to an integer.  There are many ways to do this, and really you should probably use a regular expression to validate that n1 contains what you expect first, but that being said you can try any of the following:

```
var n=parseInt(n1, 10)+1;
var n=(n1*1)+1;
var n=(+n1)+1;
```

As an aside the regex for validating the input from the DOM might be something such as:

```
/^-?\d+$/
```

Comment: Always specify a radix when using parseInt().

Answer (score 5):

Use [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
var n = parseInt(n1, 10) + 1;
```

Comment: To be honest I prefer the other answer which was `var n=(+n1)+1;`

Comment: Nice job remembering to specify the optional radix argument to parseInt; I updated my own answer to reflect this

Comment: wish I could accept stuff instantly - "You can accept this answer in 7 mins" - why?

Comment: Because my answer is more thorough ;)

Comment: @GeorgeJempty You had another answer before that which you deleted though

Comment: @DevilishDB I would prefer `parseInt()` because it adds readibility in your case IMHO. (Question authors mustn't accept an answer within the first minutes since they should allow multiple answers being posted.)

Comment: @ComFreek sorry for my basic JS knowledge... what does that mean?

Comment: My answer still has var n=(+n1)+1; I actually deleted nothing, but rather there must have been a network hiccup on my end that made it appear and then appear to be deleted.  But again, it's back

Comment: @DevilishDB What do you mean? `parseInt()` is easier to grasp for readers, it's an English word and not a symbol (`we parseInt() that variable` vs `we 'plus' that variable`).

Comment: The plus is shorter though and the slideshow I'm making is only for personal use so it's not too important I would've thought

Answer (score 1):

Use Number():

```
var n = Number("1");
```

<kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/K3X8D/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

parseInt - good choice. Also you can do

```
var n = n-0+1
```

Just remember that of you have different types "+" will convert to string and "-" will convert to numbers

Answer (score -1):

```
var n=parseInt(n)+1;
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/K3X8D/1/)

Comment: Always use a radix when using parseInt()! BTW how is this answer different from mine?

Comment: It works perfectly in this case, but the default radix is **not** 10 in ES < 5 versions. Read here for further information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score -1):

Convert `n1` to number as it is a string like `~~n1`. The `~~n1` form is good if you know you want an integer (a 32-bit integer).

Second way is to use `Number()` function i.e. `Number(n1)` will convert n1 value into a string.